# Python: Read huge number of lines from stdin

Tags: python, stdin, readline

I'm trying to read a huge amount of lines from standard input with python.

```
more hugefile.txt | python readstdin.py
```

The problem is that the program freezes as soon as i've read just a single line.

```
print sys.stdin.read(8)
exit(1)
```

This prints the first 8 bytes but then i expect it to terminate but it never does. I think it's not really just reading the first bytes but trying to read the whole file into memory.

Same problem with sys.stdin.readline()

What i really want to do is of course to read all the lines but with a buffer so i don't run out of memory.

I'm using python 2.6

Comment: Why are you using more instead of cat or even just a simple redirect of stdin?

Comment: I don't see any reason why your program would "freeze". How are you detecting that it freezes?

Comment: Ah i was running it from windows command line. No cat on windows.

Comment: I had the same thought as Mark, but then it turns out `more` appears to just act like `cat` when stdout is redirected. Still, `cat` would absolutely be a much better choice here. (I believe it's `type` on Windows, or something like that)

Comment: @GregHewgill If the file is small the program terminates after reading the 8 bytes. With a huge file it's not.

Comment: Oh, who knows what `more` on Windows does (since Windows doesn't distinguish between "is a tty" and "isn't a tty" in the same way as Unix does). Definitely try with redirection (`python readstdin.py < hugefile.text`).

Comment: Ah yeah "type" instead of "more" solved it! Thanks!

Comment: Why did you choose not to use redirection? Using `type` is unnecessary even on Windows. [The purpose of `cat` is to concatenate (or "catenate") files. If it's only one file, concatenating it with nothing at all is a waste of time, and costs you a process.](http://smallo.ruhr.de/award.html)

Comment: Redirection worked too. I'm not used to windows command line so i just googled the windows equivalent of "cat" and some site said "more". And it worked fine until i got to this huge file.

Comment: So are we to conclude that "huge" == "more than a page full"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work efficiently in a modern Python:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    # do something...
    print line,
```

You can then run the script like this:

```
python readstdin.py < hugefile.txt
```

Comment: How is the memory working here? It loads one single line at a time and remove it from the buffer when the next line reads in ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, reads a line at a time and sets it to the line variable.  Old values for line will be reclaimed as they are lost.

Answer (score 2):

[Back in the day, you had to use `xreadlines` to get efficient huge line-at-a-time IO](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/module-xreadlines.html) -- and the docs now ask that you use `for line in file`.

Of course, this is of assistance only if you're actually working on the lines one at a time. If you're just reading big binary blobs to pass onto something else, then your other mechanism might be as efficient.